"It wasn't until that moment that we understood it." — Как это перевести близко к дословному, и чтоб звучало нормально?
Все примеры ниже я придумал сам.

(1) Until that moment we didn't understand it.
(1a) До того момента мы этого не понимали.

Сделаем cleft constructions:
(2) It was until that moment that we didn't understand it. — Насколько я понимаю, вынося "until that moment", мы добавляем к этой фразе эмоциональный оттенок, который, мне кажется, уместно переводить такими словами, как "именно" или "как раз":
(2a) Именно до того момента мы это не понимали.
(2b) Как раз до того момента мы это не понимали.
(3) It wasn't until that moment that we understood it. — К этому же предложению я не могу придумать нормальный перевод, чтобы он был близким к дословному. Прошу помочь.

P.S.: идея для вопроса мне пришла из cambridge.org:


Is "It was until that moment that we didn't understand it." correct English?

И только тогда мы поняли.

Hi and welcome to Russian SE! Please note that your example 2 is not idiomatic English, and your examples 2a and 2b are in fact good translations of 3. Can you please clarify what exactly it is that you don't like in these examples and why you're looking for other translations? Thank you!

I think you can not find a translation close enought to keep negation ("wasn't"). Without negation, you can say

It wasn't until that moment that we understood it.


Только в этот момент мы это поняли.


If you are willing to move the negation, this migh work: "До этого момента мы не поняли."

@David42, "До этого момента мы не поняли" sounds incorrect grammar to me. Correct would be "До этого момента мы не понимали". But this is just OP's (1) "Until that moment we didn't understand it": it is a correct translation, but lacks the emphasis of "It wasn't until that moment that we understood it".
